A generalization of the Law of Small Numbers Theorem
This question aims to extend the convergence results discussed in Question to a more general scenario.
Consider an iid Bernoulli triangular array $(X_{jn})_{1 \leq j \leq n}$ with
$$P[X_{jn}=1]= \frac \lambda n = 1 - P[X_{jn}=0], \quad \lambda > 0.$$
The following convergences in distribution (denoted by $\Longrightarrow$) are established in the linked reference above:

$S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n X_{jn} \sim Binomial(n, \lambda/n) \Longrightarrow N \sim Poisson(\lambda)$, as $n \to \infty$
We can generalize a bit further. Let $\xi$ be a random variable and $(\psi_j) \overset{iid}{\sim} \,\,  \xi $, an iid sequence. We can show that:
$$S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n \psi_j X_{jn} \Longrightarrow Y = \sum_{j=1}^N \xi_j\quad (n \to \infty), \hbox{ where } N \sim Poisson(\lambda),\,\, (\xi_j)_{j= 1}^{\infty} \hbox{ iid copies of } \xi.$$

We now seek a more comprehensive generalization. The key difference is that the weights $(\psi_j's)$ are not necessarily iid but rather satisfy an ergodicity property. Let $\xi$ be a random variable and $(\psi_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ a stationary sequence of random variables such that
$$\frac 1 n \sum_{j=0}^n f(\psi_j) \overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow} E[f(\xi)],\quad (n \to \infty)\label{Erg}\tag{I}$$
Furthermore, we centralize the $X_{jn}'s$ by multiplying them with an iid sequence $(W_j)_{j=0}^\infty \overset{iid}{\sim} W$, where $E[W] = 0$:
$$S_n = \sum_{j=0}^n \psi_j W_j X_{jn}, \quad \hbox{ where }(W_{j})_{j=0}^\infty  \perp (X_{jn})_{j=0}^\infty $$
In this case, I suspect that
$$S_n \Longrightarrow Y := \sum_{j=1}^N W_j \xi_j, \quad (n \to \infty)$$
where $N \sim Poisson (\lambda)$, $(\xi_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ and $(W_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ are iid copies of $\xi$ and $W$, respectively.
It is straightforward to show that
$$\varphi_Y(t )= e^{\lambda[ \varphi_{W\xi}(t) - 1]}.$$
however, we no longer have independence of the weights, so we cannot directly follow the same strategy used in the answer of the reference Question.
